# MySQL: Normalize table for unknown tax slabs

Tags: mysql

I want to store the user defined tax slab rates which can be of unknown number of slabs. How can I create an easy to maintain table?

```
Example 1
---------
start| end|rate
 0   | 10 |1.0%
 11  | 26 |2.5%
 27  | 42 |4.1%

Example 2
---------
start| end|rate
 5   | 12 |0.5%
 13  | 21 |3.0%
 22  | 28 |3.5%
 29  | 38 |4.0%
```

As seen above, the user defined start/end values can be different as well as the number of slabs can change.

Comment: Tip: Don't store '%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a tiny embellishment, what you have already looks just fine:

```
id | start | end |rate_pct
 1 |     0 |  10 |     1.0
 1 |    11 |  26 |     2.5
 1 |    27 |  42 |     4.1
 2 |     5 |  12 |     0.5
 2 |    13 |  21 |     3.0
 2 |    22 |  28 |     3.5
 2 |    29 |  38 |     4.0
```

Comment: Thanks! No wonder my mind was in a different sphere yesterday. :-)